# How to select the weekly wise record in one month if we have start date and end date both and after every week record we need to do their Total?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with data as shown below (limited to start date of 2023-01-01 and and end date of 2023-01-31):

| Date | campaign_name | total_call | total_answered_call | total_abandon_call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | Rahul | 37 | 15 | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | Rahul | 15 | 6 | 0 |
| 2023-01-04 | Rahul | 11 | 8 | 0 |
| 2023-01-05 | Rahul | 10 | 7 | 0 |
| 2023-01-06 | Rahul | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-09 | Rahul | 24 | 0 | 6 |
| 2023-01-10 | Rahul | 28 | 8 | 0 |
| 2023-01-11 | Rahul | 33 | 3 | 11 |
| 2023-01-12 | Rahul | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-01-13 | Rahul | 38 | 1 | 7 |
| 2023-01-16 | Rahul | 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-17 | Rahul | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-18 | Rahul | 7 | 2 | 5 |
| 2023-01-19 | Rahul | 35 | 12 | 0 |
| 2023-01-20 | Rahul | 53 | 15 | 1 |
| 2023-01-23 | Rahul | 15 | 8 | 0 |
| 2023-01-24 | Rahul | 9 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-25 | Rahul | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-27 | Rahul | 2 | 2 | 0 |

I want results like this, with rolled up totals for each week:

| Date | campaign_name | total_call | total_answered_call | total_abandon_call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | Rahul | 37 | 15 | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | Rahul | 15 | 6 | 0 |
| 2023-01-04 | Rahul | 11 | 8 | 0 |
| 2023-01-05 | Rahul | 10 | 7 | 0 |
| 2023-01-06 | Rahul | 4 | 1 | 0 |
|  | Total | 77 | 37 | 2 |
| 2023-01-09 | Rahul | 24 | 0 | 6 |
| 2023-01-10 | Rahul | 28 | 8 | 0 |
| 2023-01-11 | Rahul | 33 | 3 | 11 |
| 2023-01-12 | Rahul | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-01-13 | Rahul | 38 | 1 | 7 |
|  | Total | 126 | 14 | 24 |
| 2023-01-16 | Rahul | 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-17 | Rahul | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-18 | Rahul | 7 | 2 | 5 |
| 2023-01-19 | Rahul | 35 | 12 | 0 |
| 2023-01-20 | Rahul | 53 | 15 | 1 |
|  | Total | 108 | 30 | 6 |
| 2023-01-23 | Rahul | 15 | 8 | 0 |
| 2023-01-24 | Rahul | 9 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-25 | Rahul | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-27 | Rahul | 2 | 2 | 0 |
|  | Total | 28 | 11 | 0 |

I used `ROLLUP` function of MYSQL, but this is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: This looks more like of a task for an application rather than for a database.